# In R, how can I read a csv file directly from a password protected zip archive

Tags: r, csv, zip, archive, password-protection

I have a password protected zip archive that includes a csv file. I need to read the contents of the csv file directly into R. I'm not allowed to save the csv file outside of R at any time. Is it possible to read the csv file into R, directly from the password protected archive, without creating a physical copy of the csv file on my drive?

Comment: You can't even extract to a temporary folder like from `tempdir()`?

Comment: Alas, I'm not supposed to save the csv anywhere, even temporarily.